# Transfer Token BSC Always Return Error

Tags: tokens, transfer, sendrawtransaction, web3.php

I use web3 php to connnect to BSC and it is work, unless one things that is to send BEP20 token to others wallet.
I created some function like Get Balance of BNB, get Balance of BEP20 also transfer BNB to others wallet all is working.

but this is not working

```
public function CreateAndSendTransBEP20($transactionParams) {
        $contractAddress = $transactionParams['contract'];
        $contract = self::EthContract($contractAddress);
        
        $amount = isset($transactionParams['amount']) ? $transactionParams['amount'] : 0;
        $address = isset($transactionParams['address']) ? $transactionParams['address'] : null;
        $addressprivate = isset($transactionParams['addressprivate']) ? $transactionParams['addressprivate'] : null;
        $toaddress = isset($transactionParams['toaddress']) ? $transactionParams['toaddress'] : null;
        $gas_limit = isset($transactionParams['gas_limit']) ? $transactionParams['gas_limit'] : 21000;
        $gas_price = isset($transactionParams['gas_price']) ? $transactionParams['gas_price'] : 5;
        
// $contract->estimateGas('transfer', $toaddress, $amount, [
//     'from' => $address,
// ], function ($err, $result) use (&$gas_limit) {
//     if ($err !== null) {
//         throw $err;
//     }
//     $gas_limit = $result->toString();
// });

        $web3ChainId = isset($transactionParams['web3ChainId']) ? $transactionParams['web3ChainId'] : "0x0";
        $data = $contract->getData('transfer', $toaddress, $amount);

        $wallet_balance = 0;
        $wallet_balance = $this->GetBalanceBEP20($address,$contractAddress);
        $payout_tx = 'failed';
        
        $nonce = 0;
        $this->Eth()->getTransactionCount($address, function ($err, $result) use (&$nonce) {
            $nonce = gmp_intval($result->value);
        });
        $amount_wei = eth_to_wei($amount);
        $gas_wei = gwei_to_wei($gas_price);
        $gas_limit = $gas_limit;
        $transaction_fee = bcmul($gas_wei, $gas_limit);
        $value_wei = bcsub($amount_wei, $transaction_fee);
        
        $transaction = [
            'nonce' => '0x' . dechex($nonce),
            'from' => strtolower($address),
            'to' => strtolower($contractAddress),
            'gas' => '0x' . bcdechex($gas_limit),
            'gasLimit' => "0x2fefd8",
            'gasPrice' => '0x' . bcdechex($gas_wei),
            'value' => '0x' . bcdechex($value_wei),
            'chainId' => strval($web3ChainId),
            'data' => '0x' . $data
        ];
        $transaction = new Transaction($transaction);
        $signedTx = $transaction->sign($addressprivate);
        
        $this->Eth()->sendRawTransaction('0x' . $signedTx, function ($err, $tx) use (&$payout_tx) {
            if ($err !== null) {
                echo 'Error: ' . $err->getMessage();
                $payout_tx = 'failed';
            } else {
                $payout_tx = $tx;
            }
        });
        return $payout_tx;
    }
```

This always return "Error: transaction underpriced".
I already try to change NONCE +1 or +100 and the result is same

Also already to increase the gas limit and price but both will return "Error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value"

any help would be good,
I'm using https://github.com/web3p/web3.php

Answer (score 1):

The error message shows that gas price or gas limit must be greater.

You should increase these parameters so that it work.